# I need to have a page created by JS display some code from the parent window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page and I need to send data (text and id specifically) from some html paragraph to a child page, created in a js file using window.open("");.

I already tried moving the script from the js file into the script tags. I tried using .innerText and .innerHTML and both returned Untitled, the id field did not show up entirely.

```js
function newWindow(){
    var nuovaFin = window.open("");
    var title = opener.document.getElementById("titleHere").innerHTML;
    var id = opener.document.getElementById("idHere").id;

    nuovaFin.document.write("<html><title> "+ title +" </title><body> <p> "+ id +"</p> </body></html>");

};
```

```HTML
        <p id="titleHere" >ProvaText</p>

        <p id="idHere" >saas</p>
        <input type="button" id="btnNew" onclick="newWindow();"> test </input>
```

I want the var title to be shown as the title of the newly created page, as it should, following the document.write argument, but it displays "Untitled", and the id from the paragraph isn't displayed at all.

Comment: your scenario is not clear.
besides  what is 
var title = opener.document.getElementById("titleHere").innerHTML;
opener in this?
could you please make a jsfiddle or jsbin and post it here?

Comment: I don't think you have to specify `opener`, you're already on the opener page. Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k9ma5c0n/

Comment: Check my answer with examples of accessing both: opened window document body and title

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio that's actually the solution, i didn't think of that

Comment: @NicolaGalluccio glad to hear you solved, paesano :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some changes in the code, remove opener from your title and id values, its just run by "document.getElementById", no need to "opener.document.getElementById".
Hope it will help.

```
function newWindow(){
    var nuovaFin = window.open("");
    var title = document.getElementById("titleHere").innerHTML;
    var id = document.getElementById("idHere").id;

    nuovaFin.document.write("<html><title> "+ title +" </title><body> <p> "+ id +"</p> </body></html>");

};
</script>


 <p id="titleHere" >ProvaText</p>

 <p id="idHere" >saas</p>
 <input type="button" id="btnNew" onclick="newWindow();"> test </input>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `window.open` you actually get back the reference to the new window. After that you can manipulate it in the way you need. For example below code can open new window and set title to it:

```
function newWindowWithTitle(title){
    var newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.title = title;
};

newWindowWithTitle('My title');
```

Here is another, more complex example, where we can open the window and write to its document successfully:

```
function newWindowWithTitleAndText(title, text){
    var newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.title = title;
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerText = text;
    newWin.document.body.appendChild(p);
};

newWindowWithTitleAndText('My title', 'some text');
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I actually didn't know that i didn't go into the opened page reference

Comment: Please, accept the answer if it solved your issue, thanks!